# gdb fails to run ELF 64-bit program with "File format not recognized"

Tags: c, gcc, debugging, gdb

I'm trying to use GDB to debug (to find an annoying segfault).  When I run:

```
gdb ./filename
```

from the command line, I get the following error:

```
This GDB was configured as "i686-pc-linux-
gnu"..."/path/exec": not in executable 
format: File format not recognized
```

When I execute:

```
file /path/executable/
```

I get the following info:

```
 ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64,
 version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, 
 dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
```

I am using GDB 6.1, and the executable is compiled with gcc version 3.4.6.

I'm a little out of my water in terms of using gdb, but as far as I can tell it should be working in this instance.  Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The executable is 64-bit (x86-64) and the debugger is a 32 bit (i686-pc-linux) build.  You may need to install a 64-bit (x86-64) version of the debugger.

Comment: thanks.  i thought this might be the issue, and it turns out there is a 64-bit version of gdb installed in a more obscure path on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks - I had this issue to after installing the debian gdb:i386 package and some others a few days ago in order to avoid creating a chroot to build an i386 version of a debian package.

Comment: That was a pretty same thing for me when I couldn't debug an android app from QtCreator. 32bit gdbserver was used while I had 64 bit android device

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but I faced this situation very often. The executable in the build tree, build by make/automake is not a binary, but a script, so you cannot use gdb with it. Try to install the application and change the directory, because else gdb tries to debug the script.

Comment: This isn't my issue, but it is something I checked for.  Thanks for the help.  From what I can tell, you can run `file` on the executable to see if it's a binary.

Comment: @quinmars can you explain a bit more what u mean by  `Try to install the application and change the directory` , i have just had the same problem, when checking the file type it was `POSIX shell script`

Comment: @HadyElsahar With *install* I meant `make install`. But an installation ist actually not needed. Follow the explanation here: https://www.sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_53.html#Executing-Uninstalled-Binaries

Comment: @quinmars , when executed  `libtool --mode=execute gdb  th` it still give the same error . i have moved the question to another thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663780/how-to-configure-gdb-to-debug-a-script-not-a-binary-gdb-file-format-not-recog

Answer (score 4):

The question refers to "./filename" and to "/path/executable".  Are these the same file?

If you are doing a post-mortem analysis, you would run:

```
gdb executable-file core-file
```

If you are going to ignore the core file, you would run:

```
gdb executable-file
```

In both cases, '`executable-file`' means a pathname to the binary you want to debug.  Most usually, that is actually a simple filename in the current directory, since you have the source code from your debug build there.

On Solaris, a 64-bit build of GDB is supposed to be able to debug both 32-bit and 64-bit executables (though I've had some issues with recent versions of GDB).  I'm not sure of the converse - that a 32-bit GDB can necessarily debug 64-bit executables.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to be checking, is really the bfd library.  The [binary file descriptor](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/gnu/bfd/html_chapter/bfd_toc.html) library is what binutils / gdb uses to actually parse and handle binaries (ELF/a.out etc..).

You can see the current supported platforms via objdump;

```
# objdump -H

objdump: supported targets: elf32-powerpc aixcoff-rs6000 elf32-powerpcle ppcboot elf64-powerpc elf64-powerpcle elf64-little elf64-big elf32-little elf32-big srec symbolsrec tekhex binary ihex
objdump: supported architectures: rs6000:6000 rs6000:rs1 rs6000:rsc rs6000:rs2 powerpc:common powerpc:common64 powerpc:603 powerpc:EC603e powerpc:604 powerpc:403 powerpc:601 powerpc:620 powerpc:630 powerpc:a35 powerpc:rs64ii powerpc:rs64iii powerpc:7400 powerpc:e500 powerpc:MPC8XX powerpc:750

The following PPC specific disassembler options are supported for use with
the -M switch:
  booke|booke32|booke64    Disassemble the BookE instructions
  e300                     Disassemble the e300 instructions
  e500|e500x2              Disassemble the e500 instructions
  efs                      Disassemble the EFS instructions
  power4                   Disassemble the Power4 instructions
  power5                   Disassemble the Power5 instructions
  power6                   Disassemble the Power6 instructions
  32                       Do not disassemble 64-bit instructions
  64                       Allow disassembly of 64-bit instructions
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your GNU Debugger (`gdb`) doesn't support x86_64 architecture.

So try [LLDB Debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLDB_(debugger)) (`lldb`) which aims to replace it. It supports i386, x86-64 and ARM instruction sets.

It's available by default on BSD/OS X, on Linux install via: `sudo apt-get install lldb` (or use `yum`).

See: [gdb to lldb command map](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html) page for more info.