# how to configure gdb to debug a script not a binary [gdb : file format not recognized]

Tags: debugging, gdb, torch

I'm trying to use gdb to debug  [Torch library](http://torch.ch/) binary file to . When I run from the command line :
gdb --args th

I get the following error:

```
"/xxx/xxxx/torch/install/bin/th": not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

I checked if my current installation of `gdb` is 64 bit i installed gdb64 and when i run

```
gdb64 --args th
```

I still get the same error, the output of :

```
file /xxx/xxxx/torch/install/bin/th
```

is :

```
/xxx/xxxx/torch/install/bin/th: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable, with very long lines
```

I have learned that the problem is that the executable file is not a binary, but a script, so gdb is trying to debug the script instead.

My question is how to overcome this and let gdb debug the execution of the command itself. or even replace the Torch installation to be a binary execution instead of a script.

Comment: As you said, gdb can only debug binary files. Executing a script is not possible. You can however debug the Shell which is executing th script. you can try: "gdb /bin/bash" and then run "run [path to the script]"

Comment: You actually want to debug your *torch script*, right? Anything else? (I see a C++ tag).

Comment: yes torch only it was tagged by mistake, removed now

Answer (score 2):

with some help from the comments i was able to run gdb over the torch script, through :

```
gdb64 /bin/bash    # check your gdb configuration either it's i686 or x86_64 
run /path/to/th    # th is the torch running script to be debugged
```

Answer (score -1):

Try [LLDB Debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLDB_(debugger)) (`lldb`) instead which aims to replace GNU Debugger (`gdb`).

It's available by default on BSD/OS X, on Linux install via: `sudo apt-get install lldb` (or use `yum`).

For usage, check [gdb to lldb command map](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html) page.